# Does the userPrincipalName (UPN) attribute always exist in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

Does the attribute `userPrincipalName` (UPN) always exist for users in Active Directory?
Can you specify the Active Directory versions where it is not created during creation of a user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [User-Principal-Name attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx) is only used within the [User class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683980(v=vs.85).aspx). Note that the attribute is *not* marked mandatory.

The following Powershell example will create an AD user without a UPN:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
New-ADUser -Name abUser
```

Observe that there is no UPN defined on the user object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I see than in my AD (2003) the UPN is always created. I see in the customer AD it is not exist.
Do you know if the old versions of AD also create the attribute?

Comment: @Michael When using Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in (`dsa.msc`) the UPN will almost certainly be auto-populated as part of the user creation process. Older versions of AD all the way back to 2000 (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) defined the attribute.  It seems more likely, to me, that a scripted/automated process may have been used to create the users lacking a defined UPN.

Comment: To list all users without a UPN, do the following: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!userPrincipalName=*)"` -- You could "fix" the missing UPNs with a Powershell one-liner if needed.

Comment: @jscott - you're quite right, deleting my answer as its nonsense.